# How to check if there is a document with this value in React + MongoDB?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, search

So I am building a MERN movie app. There is a collection with movies ratings by users. When opening an individual movie page I want to be able to check if this movie was already rated by the current user.

All I came up with for now is to get all the movies rated by the user and to check if this array has an object with this movie's `id` using `useEffect` and `useState`.

```
  const [isRated, setIsRated] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (rated.filter((rated) => rated.movieId === data?.id).length !== 0) setIsRated(true)
  }, [rated, data?.id])
```

It works for rated movies, but when I am clicking on a link to another movie and the page's content rerenders, the `isRated` remains true for some reason even if it is not rated and it causes a problem.

What are better ways to do this without having to refresh the page each time? I am new to backend so any advise would be aprreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Should you check if both rated.movieId and Data.Id has a value; otherwise undefined === undefined would be resulting as true

Comment: Could it be that the state is not resetting? If that's the case, just add an else statement that sets isRated to false

Comment: So I've incorporated both your advices and it seems to work as intended. Thank you!